# Cisco - display ALL routes using a single command

Tags: cisco-commands, cisco-ios-12

In Junos  when you use a `show route` it displays the routing tables , starting with inet.0 ( global routing table) and then listing each VRF in alphabetic order.

I am after a similar command , for the following reason , new WAN deployment: remote engineer to verify VRF connectivity without plugging in the LAN, therefore I want to list the mandatory routes that are mandatory in each VRF ( e.g. 0/0 ).

I know I can achieve this with `show ip bgp vpnv4 all` but this does not display the global routing table , and that is currently used for management.

in Junos I would run `show route 0/0` which would display all occurrences of the specified route in every VRF across the device including inet.0

```
iank@r1> show route 0/0 exact terse 

vrf1.inet.0: 99 destinations, 105 routes (99 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

A Destination        P Prf   Metric 1   Metric 2  Next hop        AS path
* 0.0.0.0/0          B 170        100          0 >172.31.30.2     64512 I

vrf2.inet.0: 362 destinations, 408 routes (362 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

A Destination        P Prf   Metric 1   Metric 2  Next hop        AS path
* 0.0.0.0/0          B 170        100            >172.31.7.2      64999 I

vrf3.inet.0: 658 destinations, 711 routes (658 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

A Destination        P Prf   Metric 1   Metric 2  Next hop        AS path
* 0.0.0.0/0          B 170        100            >172.31.12.2     64999 I

vrf4.inet.0: 377 destinations, 423 routes (377 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

A Destination        P Prf   Metric 1   Metric 2  Next hop        AS path
* 0.0.0.0/0          B 170        100            >172.31.3.2      64999 I
```

am I missing a really obvious way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**`show ip route vrf *`** displays the global routing table plus all the VRF instances.

**`sh ip route vrf * 0.0.0.0`** displays the default route for each VRF.

This shows the default route for each VRF, including the default VRF.  As this IOS 12.4 doesn't show the VRF name when displaying a matching route, a route tag was added on the static routes to help identify their VRF.

```
r1#show ip route vrf * 0.0.0.0

Routing entry for 0.0.0.0/0, supernet
  Known via "static", distance 1, metric 0, candidate default path
  Tag 100
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 192.0.2.2
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      Route tag 100

Routing entry for 0.0.0.0/0, supernet
  Known via "static", distance 1, metric 0, candidate default path
  Tag 200
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 192.0.2.2
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      Route tag 200
```

Showing longer-prefixes on your matching route will show the VRF names.
**`sh ip route vrf * 192.0.2.0 longer-prefixes'.**

Comment: in 12.2(33)SRD and 15.1(2)T VRF name is shown with the route, except 'Default' is omitted. Not sure exactly when it was added, but I'd guess 12.2(33)SRA (about 8 years ago).

Answer (score 3):

`show ip route` for the IPv4 FIB.

`show ipv6 route` for the IPv6 FIB.

VRF routes:

`show <ip/ipv6> route vrf <*/vrfName>`

of course, * shows all VRFs.

Comment: "show ip route" does not actually display any VRF routes

Comment: ah, he wants VRF routes. I'll update it.